# How to get YouTube URL in background?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

For my school project, I need to extract Video URL from Youtube from a Chrome extension. It means I should play a video on Youtube and I need the URL of that video displayed in my chrome extension body.
How should I get this video URL using Javascript?

Comment: See the documentation and examples for chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Comment: @wOxxOm Managed to do with this. `chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    let tablink = tab.url;
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.location.href` if you are on the page playing a video.